# Android SSL hostname validation: DefaultHostnameVerifier vs BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier

Tags: android, https

I've noticed that Android provides two very similar classes as default hostname verifiers.

The default one used by `HttpsURLConnection` is `javax.net.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.`

There's another one though, `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier`, which is supposedly the same.

**Why are these two provided and which one should be used for default verification?**

Answer (score 3):

One difference is that BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier can verify hostnames in the form of IP addresses (like a browser) where as the DefaultHostnameVerifier will always try to lookup IP addresses via the DNS.

http://lexaux.blogspot.com/2013/01/android-httpsurlconnection-self-signed.html